# VirtualBox - boot partition image

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtualbox

I have been trying to convert a Windows 7 partition to a VDI so I could boot it in Virtualbox and remove the partition.

I'd previously been able to boot the raw partition within the host (Mac OS X).

I used `dd` to create an image of the *partition*, not the entire disk.  Stupid

I then deleted the partition. Stupider.

Now, when I create a Virtualbox machine I can attach the drive but it will not boot.

I've tried the standard Windows boot recovery options but they have not been successful. In `diskpart` I can't even select the partition, and it won't mount in a Linux live OS.

I think (know) it is because I only pulled an image of the partition and not the drive, so there is no partition table or boot record. I no longer have access to the raw partition or drive.

So my question is - given a raw image of a partition, what do I need to do to create a bootable drive in Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a new *drive* image with one partition, then restoring my *partition* backup into that, then using the new drive image in my virtual machine.  It wasn't easy though, so here are the specific steps - though I am not sure all steps were necessary -

1. Created a new, empty 130GB image using `dd if=/dev/zero of=disk1.img bs=1 count=1 seek=130g` (It had to be slightly bigger than the original image of 126GB.)
2. Used `sudo fdisk -e disk1.img` to create a partition table and MBR on that image, with one partition.
3. Mounted the new image directly in Mac OS X Finder, then used Mac OS X `Disk Utility` to restore the backed up partition image onto the new partition within the drive image.
4. Converted the image to a VDI using `VBoxManage convertfromraw disk1.img Windows.vdi`
5. At this point, I thought it would work so attached it to a Virtual machine as a boot drive, but unfortunately this created 'A disk read error occurred' messages.
6. Booted that virtual machine to Windows 7 recovery, then ran `bootsect.exe /FixBoot` and `bootsect.exe /FixMbr`
7. Still has 'A disk read error occurred' messages, so ...
8. Attached the drive image within an existing Virtual machine, but as a secondary drive.
9. Ran `testdisk` on the drive *within the guest* (so it treated it as a normal drive, not an image).
10. Checked and updated the partition structure, and boot sectors until `testdisk` stopped complaining.
11. Rebooted the virtual machine with the new image as the primary drive and ... BINGO!

Credit goes to these pages:

- The general idea - http://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/itl/honeypot/ddtutorial.txt
- Fixing the disk read error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020633/virtualbox-a-disk-read-error-occurred-after-migrating-win-xp-to-virtualbox
- What I should have done - https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try and boot the VM off a linux live cd image. From there you can use gparted or testdisk to repair the disk structure.

Thought, often in these situations it is better to simply install windows as a vm and move the files from the image across to the newly installed partitions/disk image.

Comment: Thanks - `testdisk` was the final piece of the puzzle actually, but it was quite complicated so will reply with full instructions!